# SQLite: generating customer counts for a date range (months) using a normalized table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sales funnel dataset in SQLite and each row represents a movement through the funnel. As there are quite a few ways a potential customer can move through the funnel (and possibly even go backwards), I wasn't planning on flattening/denormalizing the table. How could I calculate "the number of customers per month up to today"?

```
customer | opp_value | status_old   | status_new | current_status | status_change_date | current_lead_status | lead_created_date
cust_8   | 22        | confirmed    | paying     | paying         | 2020-01-01         | Customer            | 2020-01-01
cust_9   | 23        | confirmed    | paying     | churned        | 2020-01-03         | Customer            | 2020-01-02
cust_9   | 23        | paying       | churned    | churned        | 2020-03-24         | Customer            | 2020-02-25
cust_13  | 30        | negotiation  | lost       | paying         | 2020-04-03         | Lost                | 2020-03-20
cust_14  | 45        | qualified    | confirmed  | paying         | 2020-03-03         | Customer            | 2020-02-28
cust_14  | 45        | confirmed    | paying     | paying         | 2020-04-03         | Customer            | 2020-02-28
...      | ...       | ...          | ...        | ...            | ...                | ...                 | ...
```

We're assuming we use end-of-month as definition for whether a customer is still with us.

The result, with the above data should be:

```
month    | customers
Jan-2020 | 2          (cust_8, cust_9)
Feb-2020 | 1          (cust_8, cust_9) 
Mar-2020 | 1          (cust_8) # cust_9 churned
Apr-2020 | 2          (cust_8, cust_14)
May-2020 | 2          (cust_8, cust_14)
```

The part I'd really like to understand is how to create the `month` column, as I can't rely on the dates of `status_change_date` as there might be missing records. Would one have to manually generate that column? I know I can generate dates manually using:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cnt (
   x
) AS (
  SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
  SELECT x + 1
  FROM cnt
  LIMIT (
    SELECT
      ROUND(((julianday ('2020-05-01') - julianday ('2020-01-01')) / 30) + 1))
)

SELECT
  date(julianday ('2020-01-01'), '+' || x || ' month') AS month
FROM cnt
```

but wondering if there is a better way? Would it possibly be easier to create a snapshot table and generate the current state of each customer for each date?

Comment: Yes, you can create a formal table containing the dates.  Do you need help with that, or do you need help with generating the results you showed above?

Comment: Probably both, but currently mostly stuck on the dates part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dates, you can use a brute-force method.  This determines the most recent status for each customer for each date:

```
select d.date,
       sum(as_of_status = 'paying')
from (select distinct d.date, t.customer,
             first_value(status_new) over (partition by d.date, t.customer order by t. status_change_date desc) as as_of_status
      from dates d join
           t
           on t.status_change_date <= d.date
     ) dc
group by d.date
order by d.date;
```